# Manage entered email-contacts in HTML form as removable blocks with [x] button similar to Gmail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, user-interface, forms

Are there solutions to manage entered email-contacts in HTML forms as removable blocks with [x] buttons, similar to Gmail?

Instead of generic text input with comma-separated e-mails I want to have more advanced field with autocomplete (not a question here) and autoreplace for entered e-mails where each e-mail becomes a block with quick remove [x] button.

Of course, it's not very complicated to write the solution manually, but I'm sure this has been solved before.

Quick example of what I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/JNVgq/4/

```
<div class="wrap">
    <input class="shadow" value="test@email.com, other@email.com" />
    <div class="email"> test@email.com <a href="#">&times;</a> </div>
    <div class="email"> other@email.com <a href="#">&times;</a> </div>
    <input class="current" value="second@e" />
</div>
```

Found myself unable to google this stuff with no exact and clear keywords.

Comment: So are you asking how to make the `x` button work?

Comment: There is a jQuery listbox plugin which does this exactly. I used it for a project a year or two ago. If I can find it again, I'll post a link.

Comment: There are few plugins like [tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) and [tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) that may help

Comment: Yep, Tag-it seems more like it. Will try it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go: [Chosen jQuery Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

You can modify the code to use a text box instead of list box to accomplish what you are looking for.  See the `multiple select` example.

EDIT:
[Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) mentioned [anpsmn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473016/anpsmn) by looks exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that I used for this (which includes the autocomplete part either from static list or server-side endpoint) is [jquery-tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)